# ATI Radeon 5770: Which combinations of 3 screens are possible? (In terms of connection: DSUB, DVI, HDMI, DP)

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dvi, amd-radeon, displayport

My Radeon 5770 has 2 DVI, 1 HDMI and 1 DP socket, the following are used:

1 DVI digital
1 DVI -> DSUB analog

Now I want to add another monitor with an analog DSUB connection (a 15" one, not much space left on my desk).

The question is: Can I do this? I have searched high and low and people only had different combinations yet. What I want to know is WHICH combinations are actually possible? I know one thing: The card only has two frequency providers for HDMI/DVI, so only two digital HDMI/DVI monitors are possible. But I do not know about how many analog ones are possible.

I also heard about passive display port adapters for D-SUB. Do they work in this case? This is the only socket I would have left right now. If there is any other possibility (like getting one DVI monitor through DP through a passive adapter or something?), please do tell. What I need one digital DVI and two analog D-SUB monitors.

Comment: This depends on the specific vendor's build of the card!  Can you clarify EXACTLY what card it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the research that I did for my card, what I came up with is that in order to use 3 displays, one has to be DP, and the other two can be a mix of the rest of them.

Comment: So it has to use the DisplayPort protocol? That would contradict with my statement that there are two frequency generators for DVI and HDMI, thus there can only be two DVI/HDMI screens. But what you said would mean there is more than one "module" for VGA output to DSUB...

Comment: Alright, the two reference frequencies are for DVI, HDMI AND VGA. So the third one has to be displayport. I'm going to look for an active adaptor to vga.. The DVI ones are expensive as hell.

Comment: Can you tell me if this VGA adapter: http://www.amazon.de/DELOCK-Adapter-Displayport-St-VGA-Bu-weiss/dp/B003W7N75I/ref=sr_1_26?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1308653885&sr=1-26 (I know, DELOCK is a German Company) is active? I'd be glad to know that, it'd be an instant buy.

Comment: I don't know if it is, I couldn't find anything on it that said whether it was active or passive.

Comment: I sent a mail to DELOCK. If they say yes, I will buy the adapter.. Other than that: Answer accepted even though I can't yet confirm.

Comment: Hopefully it will work for what you need it too. It would be nice to not have to buy an expensive adapter or an expensive monitor in order to use that port in the first place.